# Cant start zabbix server while firewall on

Tags: linux, firewall, selinux, zabbix

I installed zabbix server and its prerequisites and did not get any error during the process. But at the end when i type systemctl start zabbix-server

```
Job for zabbix-server.service failed because a configured resource limit was exceeded.
```

this was all i get. I finally manage to overcome this by disabling firewall and selinux. Since i am new to linux i am not sure what i did is correct or not and i would like to know what should i do to get firewall back and still start zabbix server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to check in zabbix_server.conf the values of

CacheSize=3G

HistoryCacheSize=1G

HistoryIndexCacheSize=8M

and etc.

Probably you don't have enough memory to run zabbix, adjust this parameters according to your memory size.